# Php Getting Json format out of SQL Query Output

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am doing a query to mysql table like this:

```
// Perform queries
$sth = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM statistics");

$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows['cols'] = $r;
}
```

print json_encode($rows);

But this is coming out like this:

```
[{"id":"3","session_id":"22052015","user_id":"2","house":"3","cars":"30","bikes":"40","code":"22"}]
```

I need this format:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create two seperate arrays yourself.
one containing the keys and one containing the values, and merge these in a JSON using 
array("cols" => $arrayCols, "rows" => $arrayRows);

Have a look at the array_keys and array_values functions in php to get this accomplished.